# Can't understand what this text is saying

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following a tutorial and got to this point: http://rubysource.com/building-your-first-rails-application-views-and-controllers/

```
rails generate controller urls new
```

> The reason we only passed in the new action (instead of new, create,
>   and show) is because Rails automatically generates a dummy view for
>   each action included in the generator call. In this case, we only want
>   a dummy view for the new action, so we exclude the others.

So why we only need to create the controller for new? Can someone plase explain it in a little more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is used to create the `UrlsController` with only one method: `new`.

This command will also automatically create a view file for you in:

```
app/views/urls/new.html.erb
```

Had you supplied more arguments like:

```
rails generate controller urls new create show
```

You would have gotten:

```
app/views/urls/new.html.erb
app/views/urls/create.html.erb
app/views/urls/show.html.erb
```

Since the tutorial only needs the `new` view it was unnecessary to create the additional views, hence those additional arguments were not added to the `generate` command.

Later in the tutorial you manually add the `create` and `show` methods, but you never add views for those methods (since those methods will not be needing specific views files in this application).

So: what you did was create the controller `UrlsController` with one method `new`, and the corresponding view for that method. The rest of the methods you will code in manually later in the tutorial so there was no need to auto-generate anything else (`create` or `show`).

Answer (score 1):

This will only create the new action in the controller and should skip the other ones.

EDIT:
It will generate a controller called UrlsController in app/controllers and in that controller there will only be one method called action which corresponds to a route or url called *urls/new*

Comment: so far from my learning I understand that with a generate command like that we will have a class names urls in the controller that will have a action named "new" and will also will create a get for it in routes.rb .... What else?